# jQuery does not load in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I am building a Phonegap application for android.  I am trying to load jQuery and it gets loaded fine in Google Chrome both on my PC and mobile but not in the Phonegap Preview app. My jQuery version is 1.9.1.

Here's how I include jQuery:

This is at the end:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem just with jQuery or does bootstrap not load as well?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes. Bootstrap doesn't load as well. But doesn't Bootstrap require jQuery?

Comment: That shouldn't matter to whether it loads or not. Can you verify that the files exist in that location?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes they exist.

Comment: May you create a link on the page like `<a href="js/jquery.min.js">link</a>`, run the app on the phone, click the link, and reply with what happens?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did that. It shows the complete jQuery code.

Comment: Ok. So we've shown that jQuery does load. The issue then must be that it is not running. Are you running the code inside a `deviceready` event listener (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984975/phonegap-javascript-not-working-other-than-in-index-file)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. I'm not. I'll try that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready)

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed, but that means this question is a duplicate... I just can't find the right dupe target.

Comment: Its okay - TheRandomGuy doesn't care anymore - problem solved for them ... they move on ... :(

Comment: They probably don't even care how it s fixed , just that "Its fixed!" . Is anyone becoming a better programmer here??!??